# How to apply multiple types of aggregation operations on multiple long list of columns in pandas in a single groupby()?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a long list of columns on which I want to apply mean() & another long list of columns on which I want to apply max().
How can I do this in a single pandas groupby() function? I wrote something like shown below but obviously doesn't work.

```
x_data_roll=x_data1.groupby(['uid','date'])['a','b','c','d'.....'p'].mean().['q','r','s','t'.....'z'].max().reset_index()
```

I know I can use `df.groupby(['uid','date']).agg()` but in this I need to mention for each of the variables separately what aggregation operation need to be done one at a time. Is there any easier way of doing this?

I saw some answers in stackoverflow but its not directly answering my question of applying aggregate operations to multiple list of columns in 1 go.

Answer (score 2):

You can build up a dictionary mapping columns to operations - something like this.

```
In [38]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 7), columns=['uid','a','b','c','j','k','l'])

In [33]: mean_cols = ['a','b','c']

In [34]: max_cols = ['j', 'k', 'l']

In [35]: gb_spec = {c:'max' for c in max_cols}

In [36]: for c in mean_cols:
    ...:     gb_spec[c] = 'mean'
    ...:     

In [39]: gb_spec
Out[39]: {'a': 'mean', 'b': 'mean', 'c': 'mean', 'j': 'max', 'k': 'max', 'l': 'max'}

In [37]: df.groupby('uid').agg(gb_spec)
Out[37]: 
                  a         c         b         k         j         l
uid                                                                  
-3.252828 -0.596515  2.170637  1.292606  0.009531 -1.146127  1.395749
-3.226949 -0.082847 -0.155037 -0.663231 -2.320411 -0.152287 -0.802338
-3.037677  1.611877 -0.813678  0.454588 -1.276792 -1.734414  0.777775
```

Comment: for c in mean_cols:
    ...:     gb_spec[c] = 'mean'  Can you explain how the above parts appends and create the mean in the dictionary?

Comment: See docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-different-functions-to-dataframe-columns) - `.agg` can take a dictionary specifying which aggregation is used on which column - `gb_spec` is just a plain python dictionary with that mapping, no aggregate is happening there.

Comment: Yes I am understands agg(). My question is different & is about the code i mentioned appends to the initial dictionary for max.